# Postgresql LIKE wildcards escape for php

Tags: php, postgresql

The user has a search box.
I need to give him flexibility so he ca do a search like client and the sql for this will be
name `like '%client%'`

The problem is I don't want to give the user the possibility to search with `%` or `_ wildcards.`
I know I can escape them .. but is there a function to do this for any wildcard/ or other solution ?

Comment: This maybe somewhat relevant - 9.1 will speed up like %foo% searches: http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function escape_like(text)
  returns text language sql immutable strict as
$q$
  select regexp_replace($1, $$([\\%_])$$, $$\\\1$$, 'g')
$q$;
```

Try it:

```
=> select escape_like($$foo%bar\foo__bar$$);
```

```
      quote_like
----------------------
 foo\%bar\\foo\_\_bar
(1 row)
```

So your query should look similar to:

```
select * from tablename where columnname like '%' || escape_like(?) || '%';
```

Comment: Why not `addcslashes($text, '%\\_');`?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can do it with PHP:

```
$text_escaped = addcslashes($text, '%\\_');
```

I guess the same applies to PostgreSQL, but I remeber reading something on their mailing list that you need to double escape the backward slashes in order for it to work properly, I'm not sure though...

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use [full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch.html)?

Comment: Maybe because full text search searches for words, not substrings.

Comment: Maybe, that's why I ask. FTS is great, but it doesn't solve all problems, nor does it bring world peace :)

Comment: Why, oh, why we always have to live with this suboptimal, no-world-peace-bringing software!